# Connection between weak topology and weak convergence.

Tags: probability, general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory

**I read the following in a book:**

"The weak topology $\mathscr{W}$ on the set $\mathfrak{M}$ of Borel measures on a Polish space $\mathfrak{X}$ is Polish.

In particular, the proposition implies that convergence in distribution can be understood as convergence $d_{w}\left(P_{n}, P\right) \rightarrow 0$ for a metric $d_{w}$ on $\mathfrak{M}$. There are several possibilities for this metric, for instance, the bounded Lipschitz metric
$$
d_{w}(P, Q)=\sup _{\psi}\left|\int \psi d P-\int \psi d Q\right|
$$
where the supremum is taken over all functions  $\psi: \mathfrak{X} \rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $|\psi(x)-\psi(y)| \leq d(x, y) $, for every $x, y \in \mathfrak{X}$. "

**And now the interesting part:**

"This metric can also be defined on the set of all signed measures on $(\mathfrak{X}, \mathscr{X})$, the linear span of probability measures, and be derived from a norm on this space. The dual of the resulting normed space is the space of bounded continuous functions and the weak topology can be understood in terms of the functional analytic concept of the same name."

$\textbf{Q}:$ **Can someone provide me with a proof of the fact that "the weak topology can be understood in terms of the functional analytic concept of the same name."?**

Comment: Hmm, the Riesz-(Markov?) representation theorems might be of assistance here, in linking continuous functions, measure, and dual space

Comment: This is really good presentation for a first question. Welcome to the site!

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Thank you!

Comment: Wait. To me, the weak topology *only* means the concept from functional analysis. What definition of weak topology $\mathscr{W}$ on $\mathfrak{M}$ do you use?

Comment: Definition The weak topology on the set $\mathfrak{M}$ of all probability measures on a given Polish space $(\mathfrak{X}, \mathscr{X})$ with its Borel $\sigma$-field, is the weakest topology such that all maps $P \mapsto \int \psi d P$, for a bounded continuous function $\psi: \mathfrak{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, are continuous. Equivalently, it is the topology such that $P_{n} \rightarrow P$ if and only if $\int \psi d P_{n} \rightarrow \int \psi d P$, for every bounded continuous function $\psi: \mathfrak{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The last sentence gives the connection. However I was wondering if there is something deeper, other than that.

Comment: Could you please cite the book?